# How to install ConvenienceKit Framework via Podfile Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I've tried multiple methods and Xcode versions to install this method and use it but every time when i use import ConvenienceKit it always fails by saying "No such module ConvenienceKit"

https://github.com/MakeSchool/ConvenienceKit

it can be installed by using use_frameworks! in the Podfile and pod 'ConvenienceKit'. Everything installs fine, just doesn't work.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

To use pods use have to work in a 'workspace' with the the pod that you are using. If you are using a workspace and it is sill not working you can try the following:

1. Check to see if there is a update for CocoaPods
2. Check to see if there is a update for Xcode
3. Uninstall Xcode and re install it.

Hope this works.

Comment: I was working within a workplace, the problem was that ConvenienceKit wasn't updated to Swift 2.0 at the time (the version i had installed), all working great now. Thanks for the answer though.